# Which Design Pattern suits Canvas Drawing in WPF

Tags: design-patterns, canvas, drawing

I do have an application which deals with drawing on a WPF Canvas some lines and shapes and adding many points say 1000 on the drawn line .

which design pattern suits this highly extensive canvas drawing in wpf..

Is MVVM a better apporoach for this line drawing and point plotting stuff ?

Any help/ideas are highly appreciated.

Regards,
Sreekesh NK

Comment: There's really not enough info available to answer. You want patterns in what context? To store and manage the lines, shapes, and points? or for the Canvas? Please provide more detailed info if you expect a decent answer, otherwise we'll just have to guess at what you may want.

Comment: First of all Thank you for your response, let me detail further.
I do have say 3 screens to keep it simple , and those 3 screens share some common data.
The functionalities on those screens are to draw lines , drag lines etc  and add some points on those drawn line.
The final outcome is a serialized xml file which contains the points and lines , but those pixel points shall be converted to some real world values before serializing as all the drawing are done on the WPF canvas. Let me know if you need further detailed information.

Comment: The question is too general. Split your task into subtasks and analyze them separately. Then ask questions if you don't know what to do. This questions is similar to: "What design patterns should I use to write an operating system"?

Comment: And in the first place: think by yourself and don't expect SO to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Shapes and line drawing is UI specific so in MVVM this would live in the View.

If you were to persist the lines and shapes, then maybe the Model and ViewModel would get involved, but to be honest design patterns don't seem to come into what you are asking.

MVVM, MVP, MVC - all these patterns are enterprise architecture patterns. They are concerned with a composite breakdown of your solutions layers and components, keeping them seperated so they can be tested and maintained..

Canvas drawing don't really come under particular design patterns. Sure you can use MVVM, but I can't see that affecting your specific implementation of the drawing components.

Comment: He does mention that he wants to serialize the shapes, but I agree with you that MVC probably wouldnt come into play here. "enterprise architectural patterns"? That's so 2002, isnt it? :) Wouldnt MVC et al apply to a more broad solution set than just enterprise?

Comment: Sure they can be applied to all sorts of scenarios. The point I am trying to get across here is that View/UI related specifics such as rendering a canvas isn't really a design pattern issue. I don't think serialisation is abstract enough to warrant a design-pattern discussion either. Name a design pattern that prohibits something as specific as serialisation of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic overview of the design that you could consider using:

(Im a C++ guy, but I think you'll get the idea)

```
class ScreenBase
{
public:
    // define abstract operations here, may consider different return types
    // These may be Template Patterns depending
    // if there is common stuff to all screens
    virtual void drawLine(/* appropriate params here*/) = 0;
    virtual void dragLine(/* appropriate params here*/) = 0;
    virtual void deleteLine(/* appropriate params here*/) = 0;
    // more common operations

    // Use a Template pattern if there is common screen
    // serialization stuff, else just define it as abstract
    void serialize() {
        // do common stuff here
        doSynchronize();
        // do more common stuff here
    }

    virtual void doSynchronize(/* appropriate params here*/) = 0;
    ...

private:
    // store the drawing shapes here appropriately
};

class Screen1 : public ScreenBase
{
public:
    // concrete operation implementations
    virtual void drawLine(/* appropriate params here*/);
    virtual void dragLine(/* appropriate params here*/);
    virtual void deleteLine(/* appropriate params here*/);
    virtual void doSerialize() { ... }

    // concrete specifics here
};

// class Screen2 : public ScreenBase

// class Screen3 : public ScreenBase

// I dont know the Microsoft stuff, the shapes should be
// defined in WPF, So we wont need to define anything here.
```

Instead of the Screens implementing the serialization, you may consider using a Stategy Design pattern, which would be to create a seperate serialization class or class hierarchy and set that as an attribute on the Screen(s)

Try this out, then as you advance more, try to ask more specific questions